# CSS My Table looks weird

Tags: html, css

I have a table with this styling:

```
table, td, tr, th {
border-color: #FFF;
width: 99%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and my table that the first column has a lot of space, which is taking away from the other columns, my question is how would I fix this?

I was playing around with the display attribute, like so `display:flex` it kinda works expect the data goes over the border, another weird border appears.

He is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jsuske/jsyoeLd5/1/ but it doesnt give the best view of my issue.

Comment: what browser are you using? I can't see any problems using Chrome (well, obviously everything is squished but all the columns are equal for me)

Comment: Is the data in your first column larger in a few rows or is it always the 7 char string you show in the fiddle?

Comment: nope they are always 7 char long and I am also using google chrome

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/jsyoeLd5/3/ whats the problem here??

Comment: I have updated my fiddle to include more css: http://jsfiddle.net/jsuske/jsyoeLd5/4/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way your code is written, every single `table`, `td`, `tr`, and `th` is trying to be 99% of its parent's width. All `td`s or `th`s in a row can't have 99% width--the sum of their widths need to add up to 100%. Otherwise, the first item, e.g. the first `td` in a `tr`, is going to try to be 99% wide, so it's going to take up as much space as possible.

Give this a try:

```
table {
  width: 99%; /* Not necessary */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Not necessary */
}

table, td, tr, th {
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: that still didnt work, the first column is still longer than the other columns and its length is only 7 char

Comment: added text-align:center to table, td, tr, th fixed my problem with this.

Comment: There is no need in specifying width percentage like this. Just do like: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsyoeLd5/7/)

Comment: @2L84F8 I agree. I added comments to my CSS. I was just trying to show OP what parts of the CSS were likely causing the inconsistent widths.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsyoeLd5/7/)**

You don't need all that. Here:

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

table, td, tr, th {
    border-color: #FFF;
}
td{
    padding:5px;
}
```